# Merging two data frames with different lengths and variations in value code on shared variable

Tags: merge

I want to merge dfA with dfB on their common variable LAW_CODE to create a new variable "Less_Discretion" which is TRUE, when the values in dfB$LAW_CODE start with any of the values in dfA$LAW_CODE, and false when they do not meet that condition. The challenge is that dfA$LAW_CODE is shorter than the values in dfB$LAW_CODE and its possible that some of the values vary in how they are coded (i.e. there will be dashes or spaces in one but not the other). Turning to ChatGPT hasn't yielded any workable solutions so far.

Here is what I attempted after importing the two datasets:

```
# Remove periods, dashes, and spaces from LAW_CODE in both data frames
dfA <- dfA %>%
  mutate(LAW_CODE = gsub("[.\\s-]", "", LAW_CODE))

dfB <- dfB %>%
  mutate(LAW_CODE = gsub("[.\\s-]", "", LAW_CODE))

Lessdiscretion_LawCodes <- dfA$LAW_CODE

dfB <- dfB  %>%
    mutate(Less_Discretion = startsWith(LAW_CODE, Lessdiscretion_LawCodes)
    )
```

The above code does create the variable that I want, but it results in all values being false. Any suggestions for how I can achieve the output I want?

Here is an example of the output that I am trying to achieve.

| LAW_CODE_A | LAW_CODE_B | LESS_DISCRETION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VTL 1-23454 | VTL 123454678 | TRUE |
| PL 2876-A | PL2876 | TRUE |
| PL 4958 | PL495856 | TRUE |